# how to sort file names by two specific parts in R?

Tags: r

I would like to sort file names by two specific parts. File names:

```
/xxx/abc_000_0222
/xxx/abc_000_0234
/xxx/abc_000_0134
/xxx/abc_002_0321
/xxx/abc_002_0012
/xxx/abc_001_0112
/xxx/abc_001_0341
```

The right order I want to get like this:

```
/xxx/abc_000_0134
/xxx/abc_000_0222
/xxx/abc_000_0234
/xxx/abc_001_0112
/xxx/abc_001_0341
/xxx/abc_002_0012
/xxx/abc_002_0321
```

I have tried the `mixedsort` function in `gtools` library, but could not get the right order:

```
df_filenames <- mixedsort(filenames)
```

Any help? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the strings into a df by the separator `_`, then get order of df by second/third variables and feed it back to file names.

```
x <- c("/xxx/abc_000_0222",
"/xxx/abc_000_0234",
"/xxx/abc_000_0134",
"/xxx/abc_002_0321",
"/xxx/abc_002_0012",
"/xxx/abc_001_0112",
"/xxx/abc_001_0341")
```

In your case `x` would be from `list.files()`:

```
x <- list.files("path/to/files") 
df <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,strsplit(x,"_")))
x[with(df, order(V2, V3))]

# /xxx/abc_000_0134
# /xxx/abc_000_0222
# /xxx/abc_000_0234
# /xxx/abc_001_0112
# /xxx/abc_001_0341
# /xxx/abc_002_0012
# /xxx/abc_002_0321
```

Also, note of caution. I can't recall what, but there's something in the `gtools` library that causes some collisions with commonly used functions and can lead to unexpected results. If you see something strange make sure it's not attached.